# Изменение координат элемента после клика

Tags: javascript

```
function handler() {
    var left = myDIV.getBoundingClientRect();
    var top = myDIV.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (left = 100){
        left.style.left = (parseInt(left.style.left||0)+100)+"px";
    }
    if(top = 100){
        top.style.top = (parseInt(top.style.left||0)+100)+"px";
    }
    if (left = 200)
        left.style.left = (parseInt(left.style.left||0)-100)+"px";
    }
    if(top = 200){
        top.style.top = (parseInt(top.style.left||0)-100)+"px";
    }
```

подскажите направление для того что бы функция работала

Comment: согласен пропущена после добавления выдает ошибку Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Comment: Ошибку выдает, т.к. вы пытаетесь взять свойство left.style.left, в данном случаи left.style - undefined и у него нету свойства left. Данное свойство есть только у DOM элемента (myDIV в вашем случаи)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myDIV.getBoundingClientRect();` возвращает объект вида `{left: 100, right: 100, ...}`, т.е. в переменную `left` и `right` вы кладете объект. При этом далее в коде у вас идет повторное присваивание, а не проверка.

Возможно изначально задумывалось что-то подобное (из задачи не ясно):

```
function handler() {
  var bounds = myDIV.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (bounds.left === 100){
    myDIV.style.left = (parseInt(myDIV.style.left||0)+100)+"px";
  }
  if(bounds.top === 100){
    myDIV.style.top = (parseInt(myDIV.style.top||0)+100)+"px";
  }
  if (bounds.left === 200){
    myDIV.style.left = (parseInt(myDIV.style.left||0)-100)+"px";
  }
  if(bounds.top === 200){
    myDIV.style.top = (parseInt(myDIV.style.top||0)-100)+"px";
  }
}
```

Comment: <div id="myDIV" onclick="handler()">
    <h1>myDIV</h1>
    </div> есть див его на до передвинуть после клика

Comment: Ну тогда ваш примерно точно никогда не заработал бы. Возможно этот пример решает вашу задачу https://jsfiddle.net/5z35ywad/

Comment: обязательно что бы стиль был в диве? можна ли его вынести из дива?

Comment: Не обязательно, можно использовать свойства offsetTop и offsetLeft, пример https://jsfiddle.net/5z35ywad/1/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь